# Can I set <p:inputMask> (Primefaces) a mask to write none, one, two or three characters?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, mask

I know this mask: `99-999-9`

I need to edit it a little bit, that I can type this:

Examples:

```
34-721-4

2-216-8

-12-5

2--5

1-13-7
```

I hope that you'll understand what I mean.

```
0-2 numbers '-' 0-3 numbers '-' 1 number(required)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/primefaces/PrimeFaces-String-Input-1.pdf) pdf page 15 and primefaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml)  example *phoneWithExt*

`9` Permits only a number to be entered there.

`a` Permits only a letter (upper or lower case) to be entered there.

`*` Permits a letter or a number to be entered there.

`?` Indicates that everything following is optional

So this could do your job:

```
?99-?999-9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define custom mask definitions as documented here http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
that is the jquery plugin used by primefaces inputMask.

just put something like that:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
          $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[A-Fa-f0-9]";
        }
    );
</script>
```

somewhere in your xhtml file